# How can I print the Dates of an equity in quantmod package in R?

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I want to load the 5 years history of Tesla equity from quanatmod package in R.Doing so I have :

```
tsla <- quantmod::getSymbols("TSLA", from = base::as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = base::as.Date("2022-01-31"), auto.assign = F)
tsla = as_tibble(tsla)
head(tsla)
```

But I also want a column with the dates on each index.How can this be done without just adding dates, because these prices correspond to specific dates .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rownames_to_column` after converting to `data.frame` from the `xts` output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tsla %>% 
   as.data.frame %>% 
   rownames_to_column("Index")
```

-output

```
      Index TSLA.Open TSLA.High TSLA.Low TSLA.Close TSLA.Volume TSLA.Adjusted
1 2017-01-03    42.972    44.066   42.192     43.398    29616500        43.398
2 2017-01-04    42.950    45.600   42.862     45.398    56067500        45.398
3 2017-01-05    45.284    45.496   44.390     45.350    29558500        45.350
4 2017-01-06    45.386    46.062   45.090     45.802    27639500        45.802
5 2017-01-09    45.794    46.384   45.600     46.256    19897500        46.256
6 2017-01-10    46.400    46.400   45.378     45.974    18300000        45.974
...
```

---

Or it can be done with `fortify.zoo`

```
zoo::fortify.zoo(tsla)
```

Comment: I want a column with the dates related to each price not the index.The index is easy

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson it is not clear from the comment.  Do you want to reshape to long

Comment: your edit is the answer.But when I run your code the dates don't appear.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson that is because you updated the `tsla` to `tibble` which don't allow for rownames and strips of those.  I used the `tsla` directly from the `quantmod` output

Comment: yes.you are right.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just print the TSLA xts object.  ( `fortify.zoo(TSLA)` converts it to a data frame with the index in the first column but isn't really needed for simply printing it.)

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TSLA", from = "2017-01-01", to = "2022-01-31")
TSLA
```

giving:

```
           TSLA.Open TSLA.High TSLA.Low TSLA.Close TSLA.Volume TSLA.Adjusted
2017-01-03    42.972    44.066   42.192     43.398    29616500        43.398
2017-01-04    42.950    45.600   42.862     45.398    56067500        45.398
2017-01-05    45.284    45.496   44.390     45.350    29558500        45.350
2017-01-06    45.386    46.062   45.090     45.802    27639500        45.802
2017-01-09    45.794    46.384   45.600     46.256    19897500        46.256
2017-01-10    46.400    46.400   45.378     45.974    18300000        45.974
...etc...
```